# Download image not working with inline attachment

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

We have a Teams bot, that can send inline images from different sources. This worked fine, however, at some point in time, it changed in behavior. The image is still displayed in the thread, but downloading is not possible anymore:

For the 'old' teams client, the download button just simply isn't displayed anymore
For the new teams client, the download button is not working anymore - clicking it sends a request, but no download is done.

We are using the internet resource sample from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-add-media-attachments?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#send-attachments)

```
return new List<Attachment>()
{
new Attachment
    {
     Content = "test.png",
     ContentType = "image/png",
     ContentUrl = "https://some.link.to.png"
    }
};
```

We are using an older version of the bot SDK (with ConnectorClient), because we handle the logic of the bot itself, somewhere else (ie, all the logic from turncontext etc is unwanted overhead). The image is visible in the thread and also clickable to enlarge, but as said before, there is no download button / the download doesn't work.

Why did the behavior change and how can we get the same behavior as what you would get if it was an inline image from a colleague??

(PS - if someone from MS reads this; I tried posting this on technet, but your 'post flooding' mechanism, prevents me from doing so, as failed post attempts account for the timeout (effectively first blocking me because i forgot labels and after that blocking attempts in incremental timeouts - currently i'm on 4 hours...)

EDIT: picture of missing download (old teams client ui in browser)
[image: No download button]
For the new teams client, the button is there AND it fires a request, but there is no confirmation it is actually downloaded / no file in downloads
[image: no confirmation / downloaded file]

EDIT 2:
This is the minimal example we can prepare:

```
POST /emea/v3/conversations/19%3A<...>%40thread.tacv2%3Bmessageid%3D<...>/activities HTTP/1.1
Host: smba.trafficmanager.net
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ...

{
  "type": "message",
  "from": {
    "id": "<bot id>"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "id": "19:<...>@thread.tacv2;messageid=<...>"
  },
  "locale": "en-Us",
  "attachments": [
    {
      "contentType": "image/png",
      "contentUrl": "https://www.starpng.com/public/uploads/preview/transparent-png-clipart-free-download-4-115822320505rpdpl1gbm.png",
      "content": "test.png"
    }
  ],
  "entities": []
}
```

Comment: Could you please share small Video or screenshots, so that we can try it from our end?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT, see edit

Comment: "We have tested this scenario on both old and new teams; both are working fine, showing the download button, and have downloaded successfully.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKs6j.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvFjY.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/stYs7.png

Comment: New Teams client version is 1415/23110231807.
Classic Teams Version-Microsoft Teams Version 1.6.00.32160 (64-bit).

Comment: Thanks for your response. For us, it DID work as well, until, at some point in time, it didn't (as shown in the provided screenshots). So, how can i proceed now? what code did you use to send an inline image? Maybe we can change something to make it work again?

Comment: Please refer this sample-https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/15.handling-attachments

Comment: Can you please look at the edit and try how the POST request works for you?

Comment: Are you trying to send the image using the Bot API or as u mention above sample you are using-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-add-media-attachments?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#send-attachments

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT, We are actually using the bot sdk, however, all the sdk does is translate to this http request. Thus, the last edit is the most clean example i can come up with, without the noise of SDK version / sample project etc. Could you please try A) what result it gives for you, when sending the json using postman. B) using fiddler, what difference in request you see.

Comment: We are able to repro that issue, we have raised bug for the same. We will inform you once we get any update.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CxDT.png